# Content aligning differently when screen width changes ( React, Bootstrap )

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap to help align my content and make it responsive. I've figured out how to make it all align to the center but when I resize it to a smaller width, it starts to align to the left. How do I make it align to the center even when the screen width changes with bootstrap? I'm new to Bootstrap with React but I wanted to use it to save time with styling in css.

```
return (
    <Container>
      <Row className='justify-content-md-center'>
        <Col md='auto'>
          <img
            className='img'
            src='https://angel.co/images/recruit/Flashlight.png'
            alt='flashlight'
          />
        </Col>
      </Row>

      <Row className='justify-content-md-center'>
        <Col md='auto'>
          <p className='heading'>There are no jobs posted</p>
        </Col>
      </Row>

      <Row className='justify-content-md-center'>
        <Col md='auto'>
          <p className='paragraph'>
            Your next best candidate is waiting for you. We have thousands of
            applicants looking for a new journey. Post a job now to get access.
          </p>
        </Col>
      </Row>

      <Row className='justify-content-md-center'>
        <Col md='auto'>
          <a href='default.asp' target='_blank' onClick={form}>
            <p className='link'>Post a job</p>
          </a>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  )
```

[Laptop View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCbuD.png)
[Responsive View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWyYj.png)

Answer (score 0):

The mobile device has the highest priority in Bootstrap. When you set `<Col md='auto'>`, it apply the layout for those breakpoints that come after `md` (xs --> sm --> md --> lg --> xl --> xxl), so `xs` and `sm` sizes will not get the style.
Also, you should use `justify-content-center` instead of `justify-content-md-center` to centralize everything in all screen sizes.

Here is the correct implementation of your component: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-demo-forked-2sdi2?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks a lot man, really appreciate it